# How do I do a media query in the code calling external css?

Tags: css

I have a sidebar designed in a standalone css file. I only want to apply a css file if not on my phone.

Comment: You can use `@import "standalone.css" and (min-width: 760px)`. Please do a bit of research first next time.  [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `media` attribute to your `link` tag.

Looks like follows:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: XXXpx) and (max-width: YYYpx)' href='yourCSSFile.css' />
```

---

If you want to import that css file into another css file you can do that with:

```
@import "style.css" and (min-width: XXXpx)
```

see [mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import)